# Parceable y unParceable en Androidstudio y .Net

Tags: java, c#, android-studio, .net, webservice

Buen día

Alguien me podría colaborar como hacer un Parceable a una entidad en android y .Net; y tambien hacer un UnParceable a una entidad en android y .Net

"Necesito ambos porque en .Net tengo el webservice."

Gracias
Feliz día

Comment: En .NET a que te refieres VB, C#, F#???

Answer (score 1):

La interfaz "Parceable" es propia de Android, basicamente corresponde a una forma de serializar objetos para que se puedan incluir en los Intents.

Mi recomendación es que **no utilices esto** para comunicarte con un WS ya que no existe un equivalente en .Net.

Deberías usar algun protocolo estandar para comunicarte con el servicio Web como XML o JSON de manera que tanto tu cliente como el servidor puedan hablar el mismo idioma.